# not able to pass theme to "@mui/system" styled()

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am attempting to pass a theme by doing:

```
declare module "@mui/styles/defaultTheme" {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface
  interface DefaultTheme extends Theme {}
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Main />
    </ThemeProvider>
  </StyledEngineProvider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

which I them attempt to read by doing:

```
import { styled } from "@mui/system";

type StyledTabProps = {
  isActive: boolean;
};

const StyledTab = styled("div", {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== "isActive"
})<StyledTabProps>(({ theme, isActive }) => {
  console.log("theme", theme);
  return {
    color: isActive ? "red" : "blue"
  };
});
```

the theme which I attempt to pass is different from the one that ends up getting console.logged (is missing properties in palette object)

code sandbox of the issue can be found here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-https-ubhqs?file=/src/Main.tsx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to use `ThemeProvider` from `@mui/material/styles`, not from `@mui/styles`. Then it would work.

Please refer to [this](https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#mui-styles)

```
// index.tsx

...
import { Theme, ThemeProvider, StyledEngineProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";

...
```

And also MUI v5 theme structure is a bit different not exactly the same to the v4.

You could not use `adaptV4Theme`, just update the theme structure, but please define some custom types for it.

(The codesandbox says `adaptV4Theme` is deprecated somehow.)

For example, you used `overrides` option for the theme object, but it is removed so you need to use `components` instead of it. https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#theme-structure

```
...
// styles/theme.ts

export default createTheme(
  {
    ...
    components: {
      MuiInputBase: {
        root: {
        ...
  }
...
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried to implement that in sandbox and it is still console.logging a theme object with missing properties. Check the `palette` property to see what is missing.

Comment: @PetarIvcec, Please check the update.

Comment: I was stuck on that for some time. Thanks!