# MUIRichTextEditor not working with ThemeProvider

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've been trying to get mui-rte 2.0.0 to work with MuiV5. For some reason it doesn't render, and I just get few errors.

Currently I'm importing createTheme and ThemeProvider from `'@mui/material/styles'`

Here are the errors I'm getting:

```
MUI: The `styles` argument provided is invalid.
You are providing a function without a theme in the context.
One of the parent elements needs to use a ThemeProvider.
```

and:

```
TypeError: theme.spacing is not a function
```

Im wrapping the component to a ThemeProvider, but it still seems that the theme is not recognized by the component. Or am I missing something else here? It seems to work alright in codesandbox with the same package versions that I'm using in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it seems that I was importing ThemeProvider incorrectly. For me at least, it worked when I switched the import from

```
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles'
```

to

```
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/styles'
```

Docs. suggested to import it from @mui/material/styles which didn't work for me. Just curious if others have had the same problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70014124/not-able-to-pass-theme-to-mui-system-styled/70014329#70014329

Comment: same. Thanks a lot. I was on the issue for like an hour...